Ensure the order of execution for life cycle hooks for nestjs services
Suppose I have two nestjs services, A and B, where A depends on B, and both of them have open() and close() methods. I need to ensure the order of execution of these methods to be
app.start()
B.open()
A.open()
app.close()
A.close()
B.close()

, how do I do it?
